# button inside directive not being disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, observers

I have a directive  to serve as a credit card form. This form can have many different submit buttons.  During the purchase, which is async, I need to make sure that the buttons are disabled. So I'm using a simple observer pattern to accomplish this.  The issue I'm having is that when the user clicks a button, the observer pattern is working fine the isolated scope attribute controlling the ng-disable is being set correctly, however the disabled isn't being applied to the buttons. I'm thinking it might be a priority thing?

So heres an observer. The subject is rather mundane. Just validates a form, and has a list of it's observers. Here's where I'm having issues.

```
.directive('submitCardButton', ['$q', function ($q) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^createCard',
    scope: {
      successBack: '&',
      buttonVal: '@'
    },
    template: "<button class='button button-pink full-width small-top' ng-class=\"{disabled: submitting}\" ng-click='getCC()' ng-disabled=\"submitting\">{+ submitting +} {+ buttonVal +}</button>",
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, card) {
      card.registerButton(scope);
      scope.submitting = false;

      function getCC () {
        card.disableButtons();
        card.getCC().then(function (response) {
          $q.when(scope.successBack({response:response}))
              .finally(card.enableButtons);
        }, function () {
            card.enableButtons();
        });
      }

      scope.disable = function () {
        scope.submitting = true;
        console.log(scope.submitting);
      };

      scope.enable = function () {
        scope.submitting = false;
        console.log(scope.submitting);
      };

      scope.getCC = getCC;
    } // end link
  };// end return 
}])// end directive
```

When I debug, inside the getCC, after I call the disableButtons the submitting is set to true. Howerver the submitting inside the template is still false and therefore not disabled. Any help would be soooo much appreciated.

I created a plunkr that demonstrates the issue I'm having. I'm using a simple user first name last name to show the issue. It works fine if you submit properly. However, if you just submit with out putting any data in, you can see that the submitting flag in the button directive is set to True, but the disabled is not being set properly.
http://plnkr.co/edit/8KTUCNMPBRAFVl1N4nXp?p=preview

Comment: I don't understand - you call `card.disableButtons()` - what does it do? That seems critical to the question, yet the code for this is missing.

Comment: I added a plunk. It works fine if you submit a good name, however if you submit a bad name the "submitting" flag is set to true, but the disabled is not being set on the buttons. You can see this if you open up your console and look at the out put.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `createCard.getCC()` the positive case returns an unresolved promise (it is resolved later with a `$timeout`), so while the promise is unresolved, the `submitting` property of submitCardButton's scope is "true" and button is disabled.

In the negative case, the promise is rejected right away (synchronously), and so there is no time for the button to be disabled - the promise rejection handler sets `submitting` immediately to false.

If you want to see the effect, change the negative use case to this:

```
if (!(user.firstname && user.lastname)) {
  $timeout(function() {
     defer.reject('bad user! bad!');
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: This does solve the problem. But putting in an unnecessary timeout seems really silly to me. Is there a pattern when your promises can either by synch or asynch?

Comment: Of course, it's silly - I thought that it was some sort of mockup. Do you want to disable the buttons indefinitely?

Comment: In the real app they can pick from a list of return objects so it will resolve immediately, or we hit the api to make the user, and it might be rejected, or it wont pass the the clean which it will rejected immediately. In any of those return states the buttons need to be re-enabled.So it mocks pretty closely a real app.

Comment: I guess my question is - what is the trigger to re-enable the button.

Comment: The purpose is to disallow the user to submit multiple times. The buttons to be renabled when any of the promise states return. BTW ty so much for your help :)

Comment: Well, as I said before, some promises are rejected immediately, so - that wouldn't work for your use case. a shorter timeout can be one way to prevent the user from double-clicking; some other action - like an alert - is another. You need to figure out what the triggers are to re-enable the button (but that would be a different question)